# Rx Observable onErrorReturnItem

Tags: rx-java2

I have following code

```
public Observable<Map<Integer, String>> getMultipleCitiesName(List<Integer> cityIds) {

    Observable<Map<Integer, String>> observable = Observable.create(s -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("getMultipleCitiesName ==="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            List<String> cityIdsString = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Integer cityId : cityIds) {
                cityIdsString.add(cityId.toString());
            }
            MultiValueMap<String, String> formParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            formParams.put("cityIds[]", cityIdsString);

            // Call the Location Client to call the API
            Response<Map<Integer, String>> response = locationClient.getMultipleCitiesName(formParams);
            s.onNext(response.getData());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Inside Exception CITY NEW");
            s.onError(e);
        }

        s.onComplete();
    });
    observable.onErrorReturnItem(new HashMap<>());
```

return observable;
}
Another stateObs.. same code

then

```
Observable<Map<Integer, String>> cityNamesObser = locationMediator.getMultipleCitiesName(cityIds);
        Observable<Map<Integer, String>> stateNamesObs = locationMediator.getMultipleStatesName(stateIds);



        Observable<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> zip =  Observable.zip(
                cityNamesObser, 
                stateNamesObs,
                (cityNamesMap, stateNamesMap) -> {
                    System.out.println("Zipiing  in Thread==="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put("cityNames", cityNamesMap);
                    result.put("stateNames", stateNamesMap);
                    return result;
                });

        zip.blockingSubscribe(r -> {
            System.out.println("Zip Subscribe in Thread==="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println(r);
        }, e->{
            System.out.println("On Error zip");
        });


}
```

Now the issue, observable.onErrorReturnItem is not working. Not working meaning it is throwing errror instead of returing blank hashmap

But If I change my code to

```
Observable<Map<Integer, String>> cityNamesObser = locationMediator.getMultipleCitiesName(cityIds).onErrroReturnItem(Blank Map);
        Observable<Map<Integer, String>> stateNamesObs = locationMediator.getMultipleStatesName(stateIds).onErrroReturnItem(Blank Map);
```

Then it is working fine, meaning zip is returing blank hashmap with two keys **cityNames and stateNames**

Why is that? And do I make ny code work?

Ideally what I want to do is to return blank hashMap if any of my cityObs / stateObs gets failed. For that I want to trigger onError in case of Exception and attached onErrorReturnItem to Observable.

Comment: Operators are immutable and return a new Observable. You just ignored the return value of onErrorReturnItem.

Comment: Voila !. It worked !!!